# Hibernate integration-test for entity mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, unit-testing, junit, orm

I'm using hibernate with critera builing queries and specification pattern.
My interface:

```
public interface Specification<T> {
Criterion toCriteria();
}
```

Implementations looks like:

```
Restrictions.eq("someField", "value");
```

My goal is to test that my enity class has "someField" with exact name.
At this time i have hibernate integration test and it covers problem at some point, but obviously unit-test for reflection fields should be separeted.
I will be grateful for the suggestions on the solution.

Comment: I don't think that "obviously unit-test ... should be separeted". If your integration tests give you confidence that you code is right (including the reflection fields) than you don't need unit tests. Except you're looking for something else like faster feedback. In that case unit tests maybe a good idea but I think in most cases it is not worth the additional effort of maintaining these tests.

Comment: You are right, it is not "obviously". I did't add: my integration tests are often turned off. I run one locally, and artifact build runs at remote machine.
That's why im interesting to test reflection.

At this time i have an idea: take the result of "toCriteria()" method, take by reflection fields from target entity and compare.